# How to make nested select statements in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, database

I have **two tables** in the magento one is **notification** and once is **notification_customer** i have to take the items from the notification table if there is no entry for that user and notification item in the notification customer table.

Table structure of **notification** table

```
nid name ....
```

Table structure of **notification_customer** table

```
nrid nid cid
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
 $subcollection = Mage::getModel("notifications/notificationcustomer")->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToSelect('nid')
            ->addFieldToFilter('cid',$needle1);
        $collection1 = Mage::getModel("notifications/notification")->getCollection();
        $collection1->getSelect()->where("nid not in (".$subcollection->getSelect()->__toString().")");
```

Comment: I will check and let you know. Thank you for the immediate response

Answer (score 2):

**You can use this example as reference for making nested select statement in magento**

```
$orderTable = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
            ->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array('gt' => $date));
        $this->getSelect()
            ->joinLeft(array('order_table' => new Zend_Db_Expr( '(' . $orderTable->getSelect() . ')')),
    'e.entity_id = order_table.customer_id')
            ->where('order_table.entity_id', 'notnull');
        return $this;
    }
    $this->getSelect()
        ->joinLeft
        (
            array('recommendationsyestable' => new Zend_Db_Expr( '(SELECT COUNT(*) as recommendationsyes, recy.review_id as rec_review_idy FROM ar_review_recommendations AS recy WHERE recy.status_id=2
    AND recy.vote=2)')),
            'recommendationsyestable.rec_review_idy = rt.review_id'
        )
        ->joinLeft
        (
            array('recommendationsnotable' => new Zend_Db_Expr( '(SELECT COUNT(*)
     as recommendationsno, recn.review_id as rec_review_idn FROM ar_review_recommendations
    AS recn WHERE recn.status_id=2 AND
    recn.vote=1)')),
            'recommendationsnotable.rec_review_idn = rt.review_id'
        );
```